# Is it possible for ESP8266WiFi client to request the number of clients currently connected to Access Point?

Tags: esp8266, wifi

My system consists of several ESP8266 based 'stations', which are synchronised in a way that all of them go into deep sleep and wake up on the same schedule. All stations are WiFi clients. All stations run on batteries and energy saving is critical.

One of the stations is a Master. It contains a modem/router that serves as AP to all stations.   The AP is switched OFF during the sleep phase. When a Master wakes up it switches on the AP and thus starts a communication session available to all stations. When all stations have their data sessions completed and disconnect from AP, the Master switches off the modem/router and goes to sleep.

My question is about the Master being informed that there are no other clients actively connected to the AP. My current solution is WAN based - each station reports to the Web Service on the start and end of their connection. Is it possible to achieve the same result locally - by a request from the WiFi client to the Access Point?

Comment: You likely could simply probe the network you are on.  In Linux you would use the nmap command.  Model your code after that command.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because *the actual question* has **absolutely nothing to do with Arduino**.  The reality of the situation is *entirely* dependent on the *unspecified* capabilities of the AP and the other clients.

Comment: You can avoid these kinds of questions by reading the [documentation](http://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/soft-access-point-class.html#softapgetstationnum) or by checking the [header files](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/eb891cd6e4c54d9883cabcb4729865b114b5579c/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/src/ESP8266WiFiAP.h#L43).

Comment: What reseache have you done on this topic? Example using a search enginee and searched for "esp8266 show clients connected"? Questions that show no research is normaly closed.

Comment: It seems you failed to read and/or understand the question. The system described is successfully implemented at several remote outback locations where it runs on solar power unattended for months. To ensure smooth failover all units are interchangeable, the system has no server, all ESPs are WiFi clients. I challenge you to find a solution to my question thru your 'research'. Anyway, I am happy with this question being closed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WiFi.softAPgetStationNum()` to return the number of clients connected to an ESP8266 AP.

Comment: Thanks a lot, dandavis! 
Exactly what I was looking for.